# Mocking a repository call with a Func<T, bool> parameter using Moq

Tags: c#, mocking, moq

I'm trying to mock some of my repository calls using Moq and most of the unit tests I have produced have been working fine, however I have got a situation that I can't seem to mock correctly.

My repository call that needs to be mocked has the following signature:

```
IEnumerable<T> Get(
    Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null, 
    Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null, 
    string includeProperties = "");
```

The method that I am unit testing is the following:

```
public bool CheckForTaskUsage(int taskId)
{
    return _taskInstanceRepository.Get(x => x.Task.Id == taskId).Any();
}
```

The unit test is as follows:

```
Task task_1 = new Task() { Id = 1 };
TaskInstance taskInstance_1 = new TaskInstance() { Id = 1, Task = task_1 };
_domainTaskInstances = new List<TaskInstance>() { taskInstance_1 };

[TestMethod()]
public void TaskService_CheckForTaskUsage_Success()
{
    int taskId = 1;
    //_taskInstanceRepository.Setup(x => x.Get(y => y.Task.Id == taskId,null,""))
    //    .Returns(_domainTaskInstances);
    _taskInstanceRepository.Setup(x => x.Get(null, null, ""))
        .Returns(_domainTaskInstances);
    bool expected = true;
    bool actual;
    actual = GetTarget().CheckForTaskUsage(taskId);
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```

Anyway, the test fails as the call to `CheckForTaskUsage` returns false, which as you can see by the `_domainTaskInstances` applied to the Moq setup is incorrect. I have stepped through the code and it should work correctly, it works as expected through the UI.

I then tried actually try to recreate the `Func<>` that gets used in the `CheckForTaskUsage` method (you can see this attempt commented out in the unit test), again this fails, even though the signature and variables should be the same.

Finally, as a test, I tried modifying the `CheckForTaskUsage` method contents to the following:

```
return _taskInstanceRepository.Get().Where(x => x.Task.Id == taskId).Any();
```

This allowed the test to pass successfully, however I don't want to change my method code to allow a unit test to pass!

I believe the issue is that I need to recreate the `Func<>` parameter as I have tried, but I don't know what I am doing wrong here, any suggestions will be very much welcomed!

Thanks

*(p.s. I am aware that I don't have all the code here (for example some of the variable declarations etc), but I know that isn't the issue as the code is used in other tests and works correctly and it would just clutter the question.)*

As requested:

```
public TaskService GetTarget()
{
    return new TaskService(_taskRepository.Object);
}
```

Comment: Show the code for `GetTarget()`?

Comment: @DavidH That just creates an instance of the class that takes in the repositories (that have been mocked). I have added to the question, but I doubt it will influence the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you should do:

```
_taskInstanceRepository
    .Setup(x => x.Get(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<TaskInstance, bool>>>(), null, ""))
    .Returns(_domainTaskInstances);
```

The method you test does not give `null` as the first parameter `filter`, it gives some instance of `Expression<...>`.

Apparently, you cannot leave out the optional parameters in the expression for `Setup`; therefore the code:

```
_taskInstanceRepository
    .Setup(x => x.Get(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<TaskInstance, bool>>>())) // illegal
    .Returns(_domainTaskInstances);
```

which would have looked a little more like the syntax in the method you test, is *not* allowed.

Comment: Works perfectly thank you! Unfortunately I think you need to put the optional parameters in otherwise it gives you an error: _An expression tree may not contain a call or invocation that uses optional arguments_.

Comment: @XN16 Thank you for that piece of information. I updated the answer.